# MacBook Pro RAM upgrade causes endless reboot

Tags: memory, reboot

I recently acquired a MacBook Pro (13-inch, Mid-2010) that has 4GB RAM (2x2GB) and according to Apple, the unit should be able to handle 8GB RAM. I bought 2 DDR3 PC3-8500 4GB from memorystock.com and when I installed the pair of them, the laptop would go into a continuous reboot cycle. I have checked the EFI and SMC. The EFI required an update, which I performed. The SMC is up to date.

Here's the weird thing: I have gone through every permutation that includes both of the new RAM sticks in combination with one of the old 2 GB sticks. The system boots without a problem if it's only 6GB total. If I use both 4GB sticks, endless loop.

I'm at a loss.

Comment: Either one RAM chip is bad, or you didn't purchase the correct MHz RAM.

Comment: Try to swop the new RAM and the slots and give it another go or try one first, then the other to see if you can eliminate the problem that way. GL

Comment: I'm afraid that I've already gone through every combination of 2-4GB in either slots. Once again, it will boot fine with 6 GB in any combination but it will not boot with 8 GB.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it turns out that after I RMA'd the RAM that I got from Memorystock.com, the replacement RAM works fine.

Problem solved. I just thought that I'd pass that along...